# What on Earth creates the number next to my tag score in my profile?

Tags: support, tag-score

I'm a tad confused about the number that appears next to the tag score and tag in my profile. It says I'm at 202 (which would be eligible for the badge), but when I hover over it, I see the following information:

[image: Hover text]

Unless math has changed recently, 31 and 158 do not add up to 202. So where did this number even come from? The only thing I can think of is that deleted posts are being included in that count, but why? Why would my questions even be included in that count?

Considering that the tag score at the left only includes your score from answers, why does the count at the right not also only include answers? Consistency here is out of whack. I like being able to hover over it to see the full details, but the number there should be 158, because **my score of 1k is *from* those 158 answers**, not from the questions or the deleted posts (I presume).

**Note:** This is *not* a caching issue since I have had no reputation changes on my account since the tag score recalculations at 03:00 UTC, at the time of taking that screenshot.

Comment: 31 + 158 + (CW posts), click through to the search results.

Comment: @TimStone: I didn't think of CW posts. Either way, it doesn't make sense to include them in the count. :/ It's just confusion there.

Comment: [You have 13 CW posts under the `discussion` tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A141525+%5Bdiscussion%5D+wiki%3A1&submit=search), which adds to 202.

Comment: Why wouldn't you include them in the count? They exist, right? Also, considering the page that link takes you to shows that number of results, it'd seem to be more inconsistent if the counts somehow didn't match.

Comment: @TimStone: The problem here is they're showing two different types of information which don't match each other. UX is that you see a score at the left, you'd assumed the number after the times sign is how many account for that score. Oddly enough, clicking the actual "1k" box takes you to the same search results, which are *completely* irrelevant to that score box.

Comment: The number on the left briefly included scores from questions too, but I complained because it made it more work to determine tag score at a glance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what the numbers mean:

| 1k | [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) | x202 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| total score of all non-CW answers under tag | tag | total posts, (including CW posts) under tag |

Deleted posts are *not* included in the calculations.

> Unless math has changed recently, 31 and 158 do not add up to 202.

[You have 13 CW posts under the `discussion` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A141525+%5Bdiscussion%5D+wiki%3A1&submit=search). 31 + 158 + 13 = 202.

I agree that some of this is counter-intuitive. A better way would be to do something like this:

> [1k](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A141525+%5Bdiscussion%5D+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3A0&submit=search)    [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)    [x202](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A141525+%5Bdiscussion%5D)

- Display a tooltip on the first number explaining it is the total score of all non-CW answers under that tag (and search should take you to those answers)
- Move what currently is the first tooltip to the second one, and give some indication that CW posts account for the numerical discrepancy.