# The tags list on the profile only shows total score for answers. It should show it for all types of posts

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page, tag-score

If you look at my profile [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3383/the-doctor?tab=tags) you see a list that looks more or less like this:

[image: scores]

The areas I circled are the total votes accrued for all **answers** posted for each of those tags.

This makes no sense to me. Should this not also show the points accrued for all **questions** in those tags as well?

**update**

It says ordered by *vote*. It does not say ordered by **answer** votes!
So it should show all votes for all posts for the tag specified.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? (yes I know its meta blah blah blah...)

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153597/what-on-earth-creates-the-number-next-to-my-tag-score-in-my-profile#comment442562_153597).

Comment: @TimStone why you..... So show both numbers!

Comment: Question score is an uninteresting number.

Comment: @TimStone why is that? I am sure people want to know what their score on questions are for a particular tag.

Comment: They can! That's why it's in the tooltip, for the handful of people who might find that information useful.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't agree. The current setup is is by design, as only *answers to non-wiki questions* count towards the tag badges.

The tooltip (hover over the tag) shows you the upvote count for both answers and questions.

Comment: eh? This is a "feature request" not a support question.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Your question title contains *Should it show for all types of posts?*

Comment: **on your update** it should show it without the tooltip, the tooltip is an extra unnecessary step

Comment: Read my post again....

Comment: Then I still stand by my answer, I don't think it's a good idea myself.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than changing the way the tag score works, just change the title for that sort view. I've never even noticed that it says **votes** before, but I agree that's misleading. Perhaps they should rename it to **score**.

Including questions in the score isn't very viable because upvotes on questions generally only mean that you asked a good question. It doesn't necessarily prove any proficiency in the tag itself.

Comment: lol oy.... I was already making a q about that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156381/155556)

Comment: Not sure if `score` would be any less ambiguous. It *is* the absolute vote count, just the vote count of your answers. `score` still doesn't convey that difference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How doesn't it? By definition your "tag score" is the sum of all upvotes and downvotes on answers within the tag.

Comment: Perhaps, but that presumes that people understand that `tag score` is defined as such. What makes you think that that is any clearer that `tag votes`?