# Zero score in most used tags by a user with reputation. Is this a bug?

Tags: bug

I came from viewing an [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour) user profile and I saw something that might be a bug:

[image]

[The user](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/21047/michaelw) has posted some scored questions, but in his list of more frequent tags every tag has zero score.

Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What on Earth creates the number next to my tag score in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153597/what-on-earth-creates-the-number-next-to-my-tag-score-in-my-profile) Tag score only counts non-CW answers.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. huh, only answers. Can't be more confusing, one of the worst things SE ever done, which is impressive in a bad way. Surely there's already a bug report about the massive confusion it creates? (Showing all posts, counting only answers, showing wrong tooltip, and the list goes on.)

Comment: Well, if there's a bug, then it is with the incomplete tooltip on the Profile page when they never post any answers on that tag. The tooltip on the [Activity's Tags page](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/21047/michaelw?tab=tags) is more informative.

Comment: @Meta Andrew T. Maybe I am wrong, but it seems to me that the post you marcked as duplicate doesn't explain this.

Comment: Perhaps any [linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/153597) from the duplicate candidate may help, particularly [Why does the Tags section of the profile count questions asked, but not their score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240677/241919) Tag score indicates expertise, thus only counts non-CW answers, not questions.

Comment: Holy watermarks, batman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only counts ***answer*** scores; questions are not included in these score totals. Thus, the totals are correct and sensible. There is no bug.

Whether the UI could be improved to make it more obvious what's happening is a different discussion, of course.

For what it's worth, the tooltip displays total scores for both questions and answers, for those who want more details.

Comment: I see. No code bug from the Company then, but perhaps a bit confusing to see the list of zeros in the same table that has positive number of post and percentage. It gives the look the user is an ashole while they only have asked good questions but not answered.

Comment: ...What? Why would asking questions make a user an asshole? Asking *good* questions is just as important as providing good answers. It just doesn't make you an expert in that subject matter.

Comment: because one can thing this is an user that posted but doesn't earn any score. it gives the perception it is a bad poster, a list of zeros is a malign input to the eyes of the people is watching the user profile

Comment: @Universal_learner that reminds me of "acceptance rate" which [has been abolished](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/241919). Perhaps you have any suggestion about the tag score display on the profile?

Comment: @Meta Andrew T. The Company should have a reason why they just count answer votes. For my part it looks weird for the reasons explained.